# Executing an update statement with a select subquery clause in C

Tags: mysql, c, database

I have the following sql that I run in C:

```
snprintf(sql, 200, "update rec set name = (select name from pers where id = %d ) 
where id = %d",rec_id , emp_id );
```

`mysql_query(conn, sql)` returns a successful result but it's putting 1 in the "rec" table in the "name" field instead of the name, but when I `printf` the output and use it in MySQL it's working fine.

```
update rec set name = (select name from pers where id = 104 ) where id =  43
```

Is there something wrong with my `sprintf`? Or something has to be added?

I also tried static sql command like this

```
snprintf(sql,"update rec set name = (select name from pers where id = 104 ) where id = 43");
```

and it also put 1 in the rec.name

Comment: It would be interesting to activate MySQL's [General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/query-log.html) and see exactly what command it executed.

Comment: execute a printf("%s", sql) to see if you are building correctly the query.

Comment: general log shows "Quit"

Comment: I did printf as shown above in the question

Comment: @user_iv: Well, clearly `Quit` is not the log entry in which we're interested.  What command does it show that gave rise to `rec.name` becoming `1`?

Comment: My mistake, so I can actually the query in the general log exactly as printf above but it's still changing it to 1

Comment: I just also tried static sql command like this "snprintf(sql,"update rec set name = (select name from pers where id = 104 ) where id =  43"); and it also put 1 in the rec.name

Comment: The next step would be to see what the subquery `select name from pers where id = 104` results in.

Comment: The query is correct but does not seem to reach the server as is. You have to confirm this fact using the server side log as suggested earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Is that due to count of record returned by the sub query? Can you verify by putting a condition which returns e.g. 2 records so that the name is set to 2? if this is the reason then (though less performing approach) try splitting the queries and see if it works this time.